# NGINX controller install on Azure Kubernetes service

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have Kubernetes 1.8.7 cluster deployed on AKS. I am trying to install NGINX ingress controller using help (helm install stable/nginx-ingress --namespace kube-system). I init helm using helm init --service-account default. 
I am getting following error

> Error: release my-release failed: clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "my-release-nginx-ingress" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: [PolicyRule{Resources:["configmaps"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["configmaps"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["endpoints"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["endpoints"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["nodes"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["nodes"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["pods"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["secrets"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["secrets"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["nodes"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["services"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["services"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["services"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["update"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["services"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["get"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["list"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["watch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["events"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["create"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["events"], APIGroups:[""], Verbs:["patch"]} PolicyRule{Resources:["ingresses/status"], APIGroups:["extensions"], Verbs:["update"]}] user=&{system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default 0296ac27-555a-11e8-a9ed-cad48efa2d60 [system:serviceaccounts system:serviceaccounts:kube-system system:authenticated] map[]} ownerrules=[] ruleResolutionErrors=[]

This command was working till yesterday and I have no changes done but it stopped working this morning. Aks doesn't support RBAC yet in my understanding and so created a role and mapping to cluster admin was futile. Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add --version 0.18.1 to your `helm install` or `helm upgrade` command. Still getting to the bottom of this, but the culprit is https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/pull/5169

Comment: The problem is in RBAC. If you do not need RBAC functionality, you can disable it until the problem is solved: delete the helm, next init the helm without assigning cluster role binding, finally, deploy the chart with the --set=rbac.enabled=false option. I found this [here](https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/issues/344) and it worked for me.

Comment: Microsoft updated the docs to address this issue. `helm install stable/nginx-ingress --namespace kube-system --set rbac.create=false --set rbac.createRole=false --set rbac.createClusterRole=false` , [install-an-ingress-controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress#install-an-ingress-controller)